# Testing multiple values efficiently in PHP

Tags: php

Okay, so I have a few possible matches that I need to test. It can either equal **A** or **B**, so the obvious way to test it would be something like this:

```
if($val=="A"||$val="B"){
    echo "yup";
}
```

I was just wondering if their were an easier way to test values without restating the variable for every value, like this (I know this doesn't work):

```
if($val==("A"||"B")){
    echo "yuppers";
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: `"A"||"B"` would take the logical `OR` of two strings. Since they're non-zero. this would always evaluate to TRUE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `in_array`

```
$array = array('A','B','other values');
if(in_array($val, $array)){
    // value is in array
}else {
    // invalid value
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`in_array`](http://php.net/in-array):

```
if (in_array($val, array('A', 'B'))) {
    echo 'yuppest';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add "A" and "B" to the array and use `in_array` method but this is definitely not more efficient than `$val=="A" || $val =="B"`